# Python packaging with setuptools does not include my source code when installing

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, python-click

I'm trying to make a python program into a package:
This is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='scroll',
    version='2020.6.14',
    # package_dir={'': 'scroll'},
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        scroll=scroll:scroll
    ''',
    # .... all other stuff
)
```

This is the module structure,

```
SCROLL
  - scroll/
      |
      +--scroll.py
  - setup.py
  - MANIFEST.in
  - venv/
```

When I run `python setup.py sdist`, a `tar.gz` file is created and when extracted, it contains the source code at `projects\SCROLL\dist\scroll-2020.6.14\dist_scroll-2020.6\scroll-2020.6.14\scroll`

But when I install the archive using `pip install ./dist/scroll-2020.6.14.tar.gz`,
Running `scroll` produces an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scroll'`
This is because during installation, the source code is not copied to `SCROLL\venv\lib\python3.8\site-packages\`.

Copying the scroll folder manually to `site-packages` solves this error

I have tried using `MANIFEST.in` file with contents below but the code is still not copied to `site-packages`

```
include scroll
recursive-include scroll *.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by packaging the module using [flit](https://pypi.org/project/flit/). I just found out it can create scripts too after asking the question.

For the how-to:

Refer to https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation